# Windows 10 installation with Ryzen 5

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

#### I am frustrated.

I just assembled a PC with the following setup:

> - Ryzen 5 1600 3.2GHz 6C
> - MSI B350M Gaming Pro AM4 Motherboard
> - Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4-3000
>
>   - Clocked at 2133MHz (3000 not available)
> - Samsung 850 EVO 500 GB SSD
> - Corsair CXM 450W 80+ power supply

I set the boot mode to 'UEFI only' and tried to install Windows 10 from a USB stick. The installation works fine until the first reboot:

> 1. The Windows 10 Logo appears and it says 'Getting devices ready'. (~10 sec)
> 2. Windows Logo + 'Getting ready' (~1-2min)
> 3. PC reboots
> 4. Windows Logo + 'Preparing automatic repair'
> 5. Windows Logo + 'Diagnosing your PC'

So the installation appeared to work properly.
After that I can't get Windows to boot.

There are no Bluescreens to give any hints as to where the problem is.

#### What I tried:

- Re-Installing Windows
- Installing in UEFI+Legacy
- Installing Windows 7 (hangs while making some 'registry changes')
- Updating motherboard BIOS

I appreciate any tips or experience reports. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There was a simple solution to my problem:
Everything works after **enabling Secure Boot**.

Comment: Interesting, why