# Windows 10 Install Not Working

Tags: windows, installation, setup

This is honestly the weirdest thing I've ever seen.

I bought a Windows 10 installation USB drive, and stuck it into my brand new PC build. The PC has an NVMe SSD (M.2) drive and no other hard disks. When booting the PC, the USB drive boots just fine. I get the menu to choose whether to do a 64-bit or 32-bit install (I choose 64-bit as I'm running a 2nd gen Ryzen 7 2700X CPU). The install program starts, I choose my language and region settings accordingly, and I then see the plain blue window that has a single button that says "Install Now". I click "Install Now", the window disappears, and I see the text at the bottom of the screen that says "Setup is starting...". Then the program goes back to the screen that says "Install Now". I can keep clicking the button and the same thing happens over and over again forever, but the installation never starts.

I thought it might be a problem with the M.2 drive, but I was able to install Ubuntu Linux on it with no problem, which means it's not the hardware. Under Linux, everything ran just fine. I also tried downloading an ISO from Microsoft and creating a bootable USB thumb drive, but the same thing happens, even with the media downloaded from Microsoft's website.

At this point I have no idea what to do. I've built many PCs but I've never seen this before. Can anyone out there help me out?

Comment: The fact that Linux installed well does not mean that there is no hardware problem, as the Windows installer does not use exactly the same disk functions. I have met here more than one such case where the problem was after all with hardware.

Comment: Check BIOS settings: enable UEFI and/or Secure Boot? See https://superuser.com/questions/1221770/windows-10-installation-with-ryzen-5 . The settings for *Intel* are at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000022600/intel-nuc.html , but I did not find those for AMD Ryzen.

Comment: Sorry everyone, but none of these suggestions worked. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I went to Microsoft's website and downloaded a Windows 10 1909 ISO from their downloads page, but instead of putting it on a flash drive, I instead burned it to a DVD. The install proceeded without issues from the DVD, but still failed from the USB. Again, no idea why, and it no longer matters. The PC runs fine now. No other issues. The hardware was fine. I didn't change the machine's hardware setup. Thanks to everyone for the support.